# "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE" command issue in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql, toad

I'm trying to execute this block inside a procedure...

```
 schema_nm := 'DEVL';
 plsql_block:='BEGIN ' || schema_nm || '.LIC_PKG.REMOVE(:x, :y); END;';
 BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql_block USING  in_val1,in_val2;         
 END;
```

When I try to execute the above i see this error..

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'DEVL.LIC_PKG' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Please let me know if you have come across this kind of error...

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Well, the error seems to indicate that there is no `LIC_PKG` in the `DEVL` schema that you have access to.  What makes you believe that the error is incorrect?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm able to execute the above code in TOAD Editor manually. But If place the above code inside a procedure and try to execute that procedure then I see the above error.

Comment: Do you have access to the package via a role?  Or via a direct grant?  Does the call work if you're using static SQL rather than dynamic SQL?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Problem is resolved. All I had to do is restart my TOAD. I can't believe this :)